# How to force the compiler to use the template overload of QString arg() method?

Tags: c++, qstring

`QString`'s `arg()` method has many overloads. Two of them are:

```cpp
QString arg(int a, int fieldWidth = 0, int base = 10, QChar fillChar = QLatin1Char(' ')) const;
QString arg(Args &&... args) const;
```

In the following function, the compiler uses the first overload but I need the second one.

```cpp
QString myformat(int num1,int num2){
    return QString{"%1 %2"}.arg(num1,num2);
}
```

I've tried casting `num1` and `num2` to l/r references and that does not work. I know I can use successive `arg()` or `asprintf()`. But how to force the overload resolution?

Comment: What about `QString{"%1 %2"}.arg<int, int>(num1, num2)` ?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#arg-14) `"Args can consist of anything that implicitly converts to QString, QStringView or QLatin1String"`.  So I think you're out of luck.